# AJAX Call Every 5 seconds to PHP Script

Tags: php, ajax

I'm tapping into the Twitter firehose to store some tweets based on some set filters for analytic purposes.

I have written a PHP script that opens a connection to the Twitter stream, and keeps it open while(!eof)...so this basically stays open indefinitely.

However, I have it set so that it stops after 5 seconds. I want to use AJAX to call this script ever 5.5 seconds (offset to make sure they don't collide), and then re-loop on success etc...

The problem is that my function doesn't seem to be receiving a "success" signal. What's going on here?

**Here are the relevant portions of my code:**

```
$(function() {
    makeRequest();
});

function makeRequest(){
    console.log("Getting tweets...");
    $.ajax({
        url: "./php/store_tweets.php",
        success: function(){
            console.log("Success!");
            makeRequest();
        }
    });
}
```

**The Script:**

```
<?php
$start      = time();
$expAddress = "HOSTNAME";
$expUser    = "USERNAME";
$expPwd     = "PASSWORD";
$database   = "DBNAME";

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'content' => 'keywords,go,here'
    )
);

// Open connection to stream
$db = mysql_connect($expAddress, $expUser, $expPwd);
mysql_select_db($database, $db);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$instream = fopen('https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json', 'r', false, $context);
while (!feof($instream)) {

    if (time() - $start > 5) { // break after 5 seconds
        break;
    }


    if (!($line = stream_get_line($instream, 100000, "\n"))) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $tweet = json_decode($line);

        // Clean before storing             

        // LOTS OF VARIABLES FOR BELOW...REMOVED FOR READABILITY

        // Send to database
        $ok = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweets 
                    (created_at, from_user, from_user_id, latitude, longitude, tweet_id, language_code, 
                            place_name, profile_img_url, source, text, retweet_count, followers_count,
                            friends_count, listed_count, favorites_count) 
                    VALUES 
                    (NOW(), '$from_user', '$from_user_id', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$tweet_id', '$language_code', 
                            '$place_name', '$profile_img_url', '$source', '$text', '$retweet_count', '$followers_count',
                            '$friends_count', '$listed_count', '$favorites_count')");

        if (!$ok) {
            echo "Mysql Error: " . mysql_error();
        }

        flush();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Is there a response from the server?

Comment: Yes, in the console it shows that it runs once for 5 seconds and then doesn't loop back around.

Comment: @Jon I don't see any code that would cause such a loop in your PHP or Javascript. Did you mean to flush instead of break?

Comment: How can I fix this then?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I guess I don't fully understand what flush() does. Should I be using it in place of the break?

Comment: @Jon Do you mean to poll or [long-poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)?

Comment: I guess I can't really say either way --  I'm just trying to teach myself how to do this. The PHP script basically opens a connection to the Twitter stream and never closes it...except for when it breaks the if(condition). Then it should restart.

Answer (score -1):

You should try javascript function [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar=setInterval(function(){makeRequest()},5000);
function myStopFunction()
{
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using setInterval with ajax requests is a very bad idea. The preferred solution is use ajax callbacks to initiate setTimeout.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){makeRequest()},5000)` is redundant. Why not just use `setInterval(makeRequest,5000)`?